# Saving large text file with sections to Core Data attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I want to save this .txt file to core data

http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt

But as you can see it has 5 different sections 
1)id (city ID)
2)nm (name)
3)lat (latitude)
4)lon (longitude)
5)countryCode

I'd like to download the file & save each section into a core data attribute.
I've looked around and could not find any info on how to do this. I'm a beginner to core data and databases, so sorry if this is a very newbie question.

Thanks and let me know if theres any other info I can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you have to do here is download the data. You can do that by using `NSURLConnection`. Then you'd like to read it line by line, to get the different cities. When you're reading it line by line, you can get each individual field by separating them by the tab-character (`\t`). When you have each individual field, remember to put them in the database.

Example code:

```
- (void)downloadAndParseCityList {
    NSURL *listURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:listURL]; //Forge the request to be used by NSURLConnection.
    NSData *cityData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; //You probably use an asynchrounous request instead, but I'm too lazy to do that here.

    NSString *cityString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cityData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; //We're going to work with the data as an NSString.

    NSArray *cities = [cityString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; //By getting the components seperated by line-break, it is easier to work with each individual city more like an object.

    for(NSUInteger i = 1; i <= [cities count]-1; i++) { //We start at i=1 because we don't want to parse the first line in the file ("id    nm  lat lon countryCode"), as these are just the field names.
        NSString *cityString = cities[i];
        NSArray *cityFields = [cityString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]; //All the fields are seperated by a tab ('\t'), that makes it easy to read all the fields.

        for(NSString *field in cityFields) {
        //Here you probably want to do something with the fields. Save them to a Core Data database or something.
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to figure out the part about Core Data for yourself, as I have not used that enough to be comfortable with posting anything about it as an answer.

(The code has not been tested, so it might not work out of the box.)

**Edit:** I'm sorry, code doesn't work at all, seems the data was too big for an `NSString`, but first part of the answer still applies. First parse each individual city by line-break (`\n`) and then parse each field by tab (`\t`).

EDIT 2:

Code now works perfectly after changing the encoding to `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Comment: Your first answer was wrong, but not for the reason you think. An NSString can hold way more than 300,000 bytes. The issue was that the encoding is actually `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. Thanks for the answer tho

Comment: Oh, guess I'm just too used to UTF8Encoding. Hope you got something out of the answer then.

Comment: Definitely a helpful answer worthy of a check.

Comment: Also, you should use `NSUInteger` which is a 64-bit int for dealing with massive amounts of data like this. Just a tip